# populate multiple hidden fields onchange of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I am populating a struts2 select dropdown with a list as shown below

```
<s:select name="code" id="code" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" list="slist" listValue="code" listKey="id"                  onchange="changeLocation(this.selectedIndex)" />
```

slist contains id,code,country .
When a value (i.e code) is selected from dropdown ,i need to populate both id and country as hidden fields .I am successful in populating id onchange of code happens as shown below

```
onchange="document.getElementById('locationValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;"
```

But when i try to figure out a way how to do this in a javascript function so tht i can set both id and country as hidden fields when code changes.
Please guide me how to acheive this

Comment: Do you have nay more code you can provide us? Where is the random `onchange` code on the second line actually at in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your appropriate hidden fields are as follows:

1) `<s:hidden name="code" id="code-hidden"/>`

2) `<s:hidden name="country" id="country-hidden"/>`

3) `<s:hidden name="id" id="id-hidden"/>`

and in your list, appropriate elements have ids = `"code, country, id"` (these are keys in dropdown list). Then you can use the following function:

```
function dropdownChange(dropdown) {
    for (var i=0; i<dropdown.options.length; i++){

        if (i != dropdown.selectedIndex) {
            var optionTmp = dropdown.options[i];
            document.getElementById(optionTmp.value + "-hidden").value = optionTmp.text;

            //or if you want to save the list value not text
            //document.getElementById(optionTmp.value + "-hidden").value = optionTmp.value;
        }
    }
}
```

And use its in your select:

```
<s:select ... onchange="dropdownChange(this)" />
```

Comment: Kamil, I have 3 fields like id,code and country in the list so i can assign id to test of optionTmp and value to optionTmp but how should i assign country to the hidden variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
<s:select name="code" id="code" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" list="slist" listValue="code" listKey="id" onchange="setHiddenValue()" />

function setHiddenValue(){
   var codeValue= $("#code option:selected").text();
   var codeKey= $("#code").val();
   $("#locationValue").val(codevalue);
}
```

Comment: Priyanka, When i am using jquery code in my script, it is giving me  error  setHiddenValue is not defined

Comment: Define whole function setHiddenValue() before select tag. function should be <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

Okay If I understand you correctly here is your requirement

`When the on change event happened you want to send the selected value and its index and another value to Action class`

if you exactly want above requirement

try this once it may help

```
<s:select name="code"
          id="code" 
          headerKey="-1" 
          headerValue="Select" 
          list="slist" 
          listValue="code" 
          listKey="id + ',' + country +','+ 'code'" />
```

create a `getter` and `setters` in `Action class` there you split that string with `,` delimiter

I did not try this one .. I think it may work

Comment: By using the above select ,i am getting all the 3 things as value of the dropdown as shown below in the html code                                                         <select name="code" id="code" onchange="changeLoc(this)">
    <option value="-1"
    >Select</option>
    <option value="1,236,SJC1">SJC1</option>
    <option value="2,236,SJC10">SJC10</option>
    <option value="3,236,SJC11">SJC11</option>
</select>  How do i set the values of 3 fields as hidden value to 3 seperate variable  like 1 should be assigned as id, 236 as countyId and SJC1 to locationValue.

Comment: Yes but i need to get that in javascript so that i can set the values to hidden variables on change of the dropdown.

Comment: you mentioned that i can create a getter and setters in Action class.Do i need to create seperate getter setter for all the 3 fields i.e id, country and code.Please guide

Comment: Yes you create `getter` and `setter` for `code` is the name of `select` tag you will get all three values with `,` delimeter in your action class There you can split the string as you wish.